# Why does my render always turn pink on the 10th frame?

Tags: rendering, video

I am making a small little video. I have done so before with success. This however is turning pink when the 10th frame is rendered. That is, if I render an animation and start from frame 1, at frame 11 and after it will turn pink. If I start at 301, frame 311 and after will turn pink. If I start a rendering, but not finish, it will count as one of the 10 before it eventually renders pink.

I exported the file to a friend (who has a **much** better computer than me) to render it with all the textures included. The same problem happens. First 10 frames are fine, then the 11 and on are pink. To fix this we restart the program but it still happens. I render at CPU, my friend rendered it on GPU.

I have tried starting a new file, everything works fine, then I start importing some objects/textures/animations from the old to the new. Works alright. Then at a certain point of pasting into the old, the same thing happens. I tried seeing if it was one specific object, but it seems as though it could be any of them.

I don't think it could be too many shadows/polygons that make the program give up importing textures. My MAX light bounce is only at 2. So far the only way to fix this that I know of is to render 10 frames, restart blender, then render the next 10 frames. I have 2000 frames, so I hope I wouldn't have to do this 200 times to finish the video.

After it renders a pink image, it will stop rendering an animation all together. Once the pink image is complete it quits rendering the frames after it, despite having another 1800 frames to go.

Comment: Does the entire screen turn pink? I'm guessing you ran out of RAM/your friend ran out off GPU VRAM; how much do you have? I haven't done many animations, though.

Comment: are you rendering as individual frames or as a video format?

Comment: @someonewithpc Somtimes Its entirely pink, othertimes its mostly pink with only 1 or 2 textures normal. The frame directly after however is guaranteed to be entirely pink.

Comment: Seems like  RAM  problems to me...

Comment: @cegaton Both. As individual frames and Video format. Either one produces the same results. If I do for example 5 preview renders, then start doing an animation. the 6th frame in the animation render will start the pinkness. the 5 preview renders + the first 5 animation renders appear normal.

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: @someonewithpc how can this be though? I have rendered before scenes that were 10x larger and more complex than what I am trying now. Also, my friend has a good amount of RAM (forgot how much exactly) and he experienced the same problem.

Comment: @GardettoRS It's not about the  RAM, it's  about _VRAM_.  They're different  stuff...

Comment: @someonewithpc hmm, I assume this is the part when I look up the "What is/How to increase VRAM". I'll give it a go. It just seems strange my friend had the same results.

Comment: @cegaton Id rather not. It's almost 300MB large, with alot more MB of textures that youd have to manually plug in to see the problem.

Comment: @GardettoRS this is going to be a guessing game until someone can reproduce the error somehow

Comment: have you tried resetting your user preferences?

Comment: @cegeton just tried it. same result.

Comment: @cegeton Forgot to mention that blender will also quit rendering once it renders the pink image. Like if I have my start frame 200 and my end frame 2000, the first 10 are fine, the 11th is pink, and the 12th never renders. It stops rendering all together.

Comment: It's clear to me that the render stops because you're exceeding the resources of your machine. It's hard to say why that is. Try reducing the size (or bit depth) of your textures or optimize the scene as much as you can. I suggest you edit your original post and add screen grabs of your render settings or other information that might be relevant to the issue.

Comment: @cegaton your last comment helped me figure it out. Yall were right. I had alot of big specular/bump maps so I decided to unhook those in the node editor and just try using diffuse. Still goes pink, but now only after 60 frames. it seems that optimizing like you said will reduce it even more until there is no more pink. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GardettoRS Please write your own answer when you've solved your issue. It would help others who might run into a similar situation.

Answer (score 3):

I had alot of big specular/bump maps in my scene. I decided to unhook those in the node editor and just try using diffuse (the ones that arnt being seen by the camera). It seems that optimizing the scene by either removing texture maps that arnt in view, or reducing the texture size will stop the pink from showing up after a number of frames.

Comment: If you can do some more research into what specifically caused the problem, that'd be nice. It'd also be nice if you could be a bit more specific about what you did to solve the problem. As it is, this answer wouldn't really help anyone else who had the same problem, and that's really what SE is all about ;-)